# How to send 1 to many parameters to a Rest Api using java

Tags: java, rest

I'm building a rest API that should accept any number of parameters that I pass into it. Is there a way to configure this in Java?

Below I have a REST API method with 2 parameters, but I'd like it to accept just 1 or up to any number (50 for example).

```
@GetMapping("/rest/bagel")
public Collection<String> bagel(
        @RequestParam(value = REQUEST_PARAM_BAGEL_ORG) String bagelOrg, 
        @RequestParam(value = REQUEST_PARAM_BAGEL_REGION) String bagelRegion) {
    return bagelService.getBagel(bagelOrg, bagelRegion);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Map<String, String>` as `@RequestParam`. You will get all param name - value pair in map

```
public Collection<String> bagel(@RequestParam Map<String, String> paramMap){
    ...
}
```

You can send param this way

```
...rest/bagel?bagelOrg=mgr&bagelRegion=region
```

Then your map will be

```
paramMap= {bagelOrg=mgr, bagelRegion=region}
```

Comment: So how would this work exactly regarding the url. Like, ....rest/bagel?paraMap=bagel1&paramMap=bagel2&paramMap=bagel3     ?

Comment: Great, this is definitely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I think I have one more question though. How would this work with multiple pairs? Like if I had 5 different orgs and 5 different regions

Comment: I don't understand your question actually, you can set multiple string-string key-value pair here

Comment: Okay, let's say I want to accept X amount of serial numbers strings. Where X is anywhere between 1 and 500. How would I accept 500 serial numbers? Would they just be added to a single list, and if so, what would the REST API URL look like?

Comment: You have to set like `bagelOrg1=mgr&bagelOrg2=mgr&bagelOrg3=mgr&....` or you can send like `&bagelOrg=mgr1,mgr2,mgr3`  and then split the string by comma and make a list

Comment: That's fantastic.